# How to install RapidSSL ssl certificate and CA-Bundle on DigitalOcean server?

Tags: apache, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I edited '/etc/apache-sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf' to include the following:

```
SSLEngine on 
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain.com.crt 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain.com.key 
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain.com.ca-bundle
```

The files exist and contain the relevant blocks from my Rapidssl. SSL is enabled via a2enmod ssl, have also checked port is open and checked error log.

The apache error log is clear and http is accessible.

When I visit the site I get this message in Chrome:

**SSL connection error
ERRSSLPROTOCOL_ERROR
Hide details
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.**

To me it seems to be pointing to the CA Bundle being not seen?

Comment: Note: I have restarted apache after each change.